# for each option create new elements and remove other if they exists

Tags: javascript, dom

how onchange remove and add new elements? i want for each option create new elements and remove other if they exists, https://codepen.io/Datik/pen/Bddmrv

Each option has its own "list" of elements that needs to show on form

for example: 
option Standard will show input type='text' only

option VIP will show input and select

Right now, its just create new elements when i choose option, tried checkin for childNodes.length, didn't help

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
document.querySelector('select[name="productType"]').onchange=changeEventHandler;},false);


function changeEventHandler(event) {
  var getSelect = document.getElementById('product');
  var newInput = document.createElement('input');
  var newSelect = document.createElement('select');
  newInput.setAttribute('type','text');
  newInput.setAttribute('placeholder','title');
    if(event.target.value=='Standard'){
      // if(getSelect.childNodes.length>0){
      //   getSelect.removeChild(newInput);
      // }
     getSelect.parentNode.appendChild(newInput);
    }
    else if(event.target.value=='VIP'){
     getSelect.parentNode.appendChild(newInput);
     getSelect.parentNode.appendChild(newSelect);
    }
    else{
    getSelect.removeChild(newInput);//tried to delete 1 input if choose 1st option
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove `newInput` element from `getSelect` element with this code:

```
getSelect.removeChild(newInput);
```

but your input and select are on the same dom level. Try this:

```
getSelect.parentNode.removeChild(newInput);
```

You can also symplify your code. Just add container for new fields and it will be easier to manipulate them. Here is working example:

html:

```
<div class="container">
<fieldset>
    <select name="productType" id="product">
        <option> </option>
        <option>Standard</option>
        <option>VIP</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
<div id="fields">

</div>
```

js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector('select[name="productType"]').onchange=changeEventHandler;},false);


function changeEventHandler(event) {
    //add container for product fields
    var fieldsContainer = document.getElementById('fields');
    //clean container
    fieldsContainer.innerHTML = '';

    var newInput = document.createElement('input');
    newInput.setAttribute('type','text');
    newInput.setAttribute('placeholder','title');

    if(event.target.value=='Standard'){
        fieldsContainer.appendChild(newInput);
    }
    else if(event.target.value=='VIP'){
        var newSelect = document.createElement('select');
        fieldsContainer.appendChild(newInput);
        fieldsContainer.appendChild(newSelect);
    }
}
```